# Start Menu shortcuts not appearing in search results

Tags: windows-10, uac, windows-search

Any new shortcuts I add to the start menu fail to show up in the start menu search results. I've tried rebuilding the index to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[Credit to [CraigsNotHere on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3mergr/cant_find_start_menu_items_via_search_anymore_any/cvk1uuw)]

Turns out the issue was due to having UAC disabled. To re-enable, simply toggle `User Account Control: Run all administrators in admin approval mode` in your Group Policy Editor (gpedit), otherwise if you're running Windows Home, open up regedit and enable (set to 1) `EnableLUA` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`.